# Creating a remote update service for a symfony2 application

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

We are currently finishing a commercial symfony2 application and we want to give our users a way to update the software directly in the GUI so they don't have to download the update package, deploy it to their server and call some kind of installer.

I know I could just code all of this by myself - but I thought there might be a solution for this already (why reinvent the wheel). Does anybody of you know some kind of bundle or premade script for that? It should be able to:

**For the client:**

- Call a remote server for an update package
- Download the package
- Execute the needed steps to update the application nicely

**For the server:**

- Give me a way to define such update packages (which files to add/delete, run SQL scripts etc.)
- Upload these packages to the server
- Manage the packages (infos to be shown on remote, when to publish etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using [scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) in composer? For example [installAssets](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/9f25cdf1aa9d78449bae11782844547c74aff31e/Composer/ScriptHandler.php#L130) execute in [every update](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/composer.json#L42). So, you can create something like "UpdateBundle" with composer script, the will check if application need some update. And GUI will only run "composer update"